# Flurry.h not found through bridging header when using cocoapods

Tags: ios9, cocoapods, flurry, bridging-header

In my xcode workspace (using cocoapods), I am not able to add `Flurry.h` in my **bridging header**. Other headers from other pods like Dropbox, etc are working fine. Only Flurry headers are not being recognized.

I have my **podfile** as below:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1'
pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '~> 2.0.3'
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds'
pod 'Parse'
```

My **Bridging Header** is as below (with the problem highlighted!): 
[image]

Here is the **Pods project structure**:
[image]

As you can see above, the `SwiftyDropbox.h` is imported without issues, **but not `Flurry.h`** (or any other header inside the Flurry-iOS-SDK). What am I missing?

Versions used: 
Using Alamofire (3.1.4)
Using Bolts (1.5.1)
Using Flurry-iOS-SDK (7.3.0)
Using Parse (1.11.0)
Using SwiftyDropbox (2.0.3))

Comment: maybe file isn't listed in the "user header search path" ?

Comment: The 'User header search path' is empty for Debug and Release. The other pods should've had the same issue then, right?

Comment: Try to add ${PODS_ROOT}/Headers or ${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Flurry

Comment: Should I add it in the Pods project or my main project?

Comment: In the main project. Do you have a test target ?

Comment: No, I don't have a test target. I tried adding it in the main project with no luck. Still the same issue.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I blindly updated the cocoapods, my bad! Thanks for the effort and pointing it out. So now I can import the header directly where needed, and remove the bridging header altogether, right?

Comment: Also please add your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it. That may help someone else!

Comment: Cocoapods 0.36 and later uses the use_frameworks! statment which means that bridging header is not required for importing Objective-C pods in Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cocoapods 0.36 and later uses the use_frameworks! statement which means that bridging header is not required for importing Objective-C pods in Swift