# Can't import a Flurry header

Tags: objective-c, import, flurry

I am having issue in integrating Flurry in my project. When I place

> import "Flurry.h"

In my AppDelegate. It say's Flurry.h file not found.

I added the whole Flurry folder in my project. As well as the stuffs you need to add in the building phase

Comment: So what is the *Header Search Path* set to in the *Project Settings*?

Comment: My header search path is blank

Comment: That will be the reason then.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565138/flurry-h-not-found-through-bridging-header-when-using-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Please use pods and add library in project. Follow this steps : https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/ios/#tab=0
Add all .dylib, .a and all respective dependancies.
And it should be `#import "Flurry.h"`

Comment: Yes i followed that guide, option 2 specifically. But I still cant import Flurry.h